# intersecting one dataset based on second dataset in sas

Tags: sas

I have a dataset called '**primary_data**' which looks like this:

```
Obs  Id     Month   Name    Salary
1   10006   JAN1926 name1   3273
2   10006   FEB1926 name1   7143
3   10007   JAN1926 name2   4274
4   10008   JAN1926 name3   2591
5   10008   FEB1926 name3   2394
6   10009   JAN1926 name4   4416
.
.
```

And I have another dataset called '**selection**' which looks like this:

```
Obs Id
1   10006
2   10008
.
.
```

Note: **Id**s are unique in '**selection**' dataset

I need to take a subset of **primary_data** where the **Id**s are taken from '**selection**' dataset. I tried merge but I am getting the whole **primary_data** as my output.

```
data merged_data;
    merge primary_data selection;
    by Id;
run;
```

In my example above, I would like **merged_data** to have entries corresponding to **Id**s: 10006 and 10008 but not from Ids 10007 and 10009. That is, **merged_data** should look like:

```
Obs  Id     Month   Name    Salary
1   10006   JAN1926 name1   3273
2   10006   FEB1926 name1   7143
3   10008   JAN1926 name3   2591
4   10008   FEB1926 name3   2394
.
.
```

I do not understand, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use datastep to merge, you need to use `in table option`, because you want to use `inner join`.

e.g. in `in2 variable` you have information if record from `selection table` was used in output record:

```
data merged_data;
    merge primary_data(in=in1) selection(in=in2);
    by Id;

    if in1 and in2; /* inner join */
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is what I needed precisely :). I did not knew about inner join.

Comment: Good method, but I think you should not use `in1` and `in2` but instead descriptive names.

Comment: @Joe I think that depends on the situation.  At a company I used to work at we had three letter acronyms for every table that were standardized and that worked great.  Where I work now that's just not possible because we pull from so many different systems.  Instead we just use `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.  When people do try and use descriptive names it actually makes it worse as you still need to cross reference the alias to check the actual table name (and sometimes the aliases used are misleading).  We even use `a`, `b`, `c` on our join aliases here and that works fine too.

Comment: I'd love to see the specific scenario where you couldn't have something at least as specific as an abbreviated table name.  If you're doing macros, you can use the macro variable name.  I've never seen a case where a/b/c was the best solution, but I'd be open to seeing it...